# OSX sed regex removal

Tags: regex, macos, sed

I am trying to remove a string from a grep search, and I can't seem to get sed to work, despite the regex appearing to be correct. I am also using OSX, but I installed gnu-sed to make things a little easier.

I was hoping the following regex would remove all min certainties from :

```
gsed -r 's/minCertainty=\"\d\.\d{1,}\"//g'
```

Here is an example of the text I am dealing with, for context:

```
<vendor="company1" minCertainty="1.0"/>
<vendor="company2" minCertainty="0.75"/>
<vendor="company3" minCertainty="0.25"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

`\d` for digits is a perl extension to the [standard regex syntax](http://www.manpagez.com/man/7/re_format/) (either the basic or extended version). `gsed -r` uses the extended regex syntax, and doesn't include perl extensions. So use `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]` instead. Also, you don't need to escape the single-quotes in the expression (it doesn't seem to hurt, but I'd recommend against it). So use one of these:

```
gsed -r 's/minCertainty="[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,}"//g'
gsed -r 's/minCertainty="[[:digit:]]\.[[:digit:]]{1,}"//g'
```

Answer (score 2):

On my machine, `gsed` doesn't seem to support `\d` to detect digits—at least, it's not working here when I try it. The following regex works:

`gsed -r 's/minCertainty=\"[0-9]\.[0-9]{1,}\"//g'`